# cudaMemsetAsync strange behavior

Tags: concurrency, cuda, overlap

I observe a strange behavior when overlapping data transfer and kernel execution in CUDA.

When calling `cudaMemcpyAsync` after `cudaMemsetAsync` although the `cudaMemsetAsync` does overlap with the compute kernel the `cudaMemcpyAsync` doesn't.
The compute kernel ends and then the `cudaMemcpyAsync` is executed.
When commenting out `cudaMemsetAsync` then the overlap is performed correctly.

Part of the code is presented below with some changes.

Code:

```
 for (d = 0; d < TOTAL; ++d){
     gpuErrchk(cudaMemsetAsync(data_d, 0, bytes, stream1));
     for (j = 0; j < M; ++j)
     {
         gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpyAsync(&data_d[index1], &data_h[index2], bytes, H2D, stream1));
     }

     gpuErrchk(cudaStreamSynchronize(stream1));
     cufftExecR2C(plan, data_d, data_fft_d);

     gpuErrchk(cudaStreamSynchronize(stream2));
     kernel<<dimGrid, dimBlock,0, stream3>>(result_d, data_fft_d, size);
 }
```

I use a NVIDIA GTX-Titan GPU and the compute and memory operations are performed in different streams. Moreover, `cudaMemsetAsync` and `cudaMemcpyAsync` operate on the same device buffer.

Comment: Can you present your code here? If yes, please provide it as complete as possible so the issue would be re-generatable by other people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of CUDA's memcpy functions are implemented with kernels (such as device->device memcpy), but ALL of CUDA's memset functions are implemented internally as kernels.

Assuming the `cufftExecR2C` call is supposed to be done in a different stream, you can bet that the kernel generated by the FFT plan was designed to fully occupy the GPU.

So you are likely hitting the same limitation in kernel concurrency that you would if you were trying to invoke a kernel in another stream.  Kernels must occupy a limited amount of the GPU in order to run concurrently, but most CUDA kernels are not designed to accommodate that use case.

Comment: My problem is not with `cufftExecR2C` but with the kernel and the `cudaMemsetAsync` and `cudaMemcpyAsync` of the next iteration. Internal representation of these as compute kernels could explain some things but still `cudaMemseAsync` is overlapped with kernel but `cudaMemcpyAsync` isn't. If I comment `cudaMemsetAsync` then all `cudaMemcpyAsync` are successfully overlapped.

Comment: As the code is written in your question, the memset and memcpy are given in the same stream, so they should be serialized.

Comment: Yes they should but they should both overlap with the kernel which takes much more time.

Comment: If you really want all that concurrency to happen, you need to make sure the `cuFFTExecR2C` call is using a stream, and take out the calls to `cudaStreamSynchronize()` since it is synchronous.